# Openshift node.js cartridge hooks are not run

Tags: openshift, ghost-blog

I'm trying to get Ghost (https://github.com/tryghost/Ghost) running on OpenShift. According to this OpenShift developers document I should be able to add several hooks to run when I push changes to the cartridge:

https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications

However none of them (pre_build, build, deploy, post_deploy) seem to run when I push changes.

I've copied the pre_start_nodejs hook from the Ghost quick start, and that does seem to run.

https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-ghost-quickstart/tree/master/.openshift/action_hooks

I have simply inserted `echo` statements and watched the `git push` console output to see if they run:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "running pre_start_nodejs script..."
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try marking them as executable (chmod + x) and see if that helps.